Not getting proper position after remove the random item from dynamically created recycler view
I have created the arraylist of dynamic view that contain the one spinner and two edit text which is get added in arraylist dynamically by creating model class for it. And adding view to list is working fine. But when i am trying to remove the random item from list then getting incorrect positions. I also used for maintaining the position but this will clear the content of existing edittext.
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, journalEntryModelsList.size())
also noting get worked.

notifyDataSetChanged();


notifyItemChanged(position,journalEntryModelsList.get(position));

Code to add dynamic view to recycler view array list
 ArrayList<JournalEntryModel> journalEntryModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    GeneralEntryAdapter adapter = new GeneralEntryAdapter(journalEntryModelsList,this,accountList);
    binding.recyclerviewaddnewentry.setAdapter(adapter);
    JournalEntryModel entryModel = new JournalEntryModel(spinnerAccountType, edtDebit,edtCredit);
    binding.btnAddLine.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        journalEntryModelsList.add(entryModel);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(journalEntryModelsList.size() - 1);
    });

This my adapter code
public class GeneralEntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GeneralEntryAdapter.GeneralEntryViewHolder> {

ArrayList<JournalEntryModel> journalEntryModelsList;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> accountList;

public GeneralEntryAdapter(ArrayList<JournalEntryModel> journalEntryModelsList, Context context, ArrayList<String> accountList) {
    this.journalEntryModelsList = journalEntryModelsList;
    this.context = context;
    this.accountList = accountList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public GeneralEntryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_layaddnewentry, parent, false);
    return new GeneralEntryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GeneralEntryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,accountList);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinnerAccountType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    //set default debit, credit to empty
    holder.edtDebit.setText("");
    holder.edtCredit.setText("");

    Log.e("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: call again" );
    holder.imgClose.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        removeRow(position);
    });
}

public void removeRow(int position){
    Log.e("TAG", "removeRow: position = "+position );

    Log.e("TAG", "removeRow: array size = "+journalEntryModelsList.size() );

    if (position >= journalEntryModelsList.size() || position < 0 ){

    }else{
        journalEntryModelsList.remove(journalEntryModelsList.get(position));
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    /*if (journalEntryModelsList.size() > 0 ){
        journalEntryModelsList.remove(journalEntryModelsList.get(position));
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //notifyItemRangeChanged(position, journalEntryModelsList.size());
    }*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return journalEntryModelsList.size();
}

public class GeneralEntryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public EditText edtDebit, edtCredit;
    public Spinner spinnerAccountType;
    public ImageView imgClose;

    public GeneralEntryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        edtDebit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtDebit);
        edtCredit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtCredit);
        spinnerAccountType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAccountType);
        imgClose = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_close);
    }
}}

Any help is appreciated to resolve this.

When you are adding an item, make sure to create a new instance of the model class instead of using the same instance.
binding.btnAddLine.setOnClickListener(v -> {

JournalEntryModel entryModel = new JournalEntryModel(spinnerAccountType, edtDebit, edtCredit);
    journalEntryModelsList.add(entryModel);
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(journalEntryModelsList.size() - 1);
      
    });

Also, in your removeRow() method, you should directly remove the item from the list and then you should notify the adapter about the removal. And, you do not need to call notifyItemRemoved() inside an if-else condition.
public void removeRow(int position) {
    if (position >= 0 && position < journalEntryModelsList.size()) {
        journalEntryModelsList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

